# Symbian C++ - S60 application launches through TRK and Carbide, but not afterwards or when downloaded

Tags: c++, symbian, s60, carbide

My application has just started exhibiting strange behaviour.

I can boot it through the Carbide Debugger (using TRK) and it works fine with no visible errors and is left installed on the device.

Any further attempts to launch the application fail, even after a restart. Uninstalling and downloading the .sisx file manually also doesn't work.

Has anyone had any experience like this? Could it be some resource file that is missing, or is there any other way I can find out what is happening?

Comment: Do you get any errors when the application fails to launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install [ErrRd](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Extended_panic_code) sis file to enable your phone to show extended panics - maybe this will give you some hints. If you get "Menu -1" then most probably you are missing some resource file or library. Also if you use DLL files then check that they have at least the same capabilities than your EXE file.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend to register into Nokia Developers Forum - you can find your answers from there quiker and from experts.